# Executing a dynamically named function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

Struggling with this one, and I can't seem to find a good resource on it.

Background: I'm creating a *step* system, and I'm passing the direcition/order within an attribute `data-step="1"`. This controls the ID that will be shown (that parts easy), but also the function that needs to be called in order to grab the correct information.

**The question is basically**, how can I **call** a function who's name I need to build dynamically?

**IE:**
    `step1(); step2();` Except I want to dynamically ADD that number in there.

```
// In an essense, what I'm trying to achieve:
// It's always called step and then followed by a number

[step + directionNumber](); // which isn't working
```

Also trying to avoid using `eval` since we all know it's evil :)

Comment: If I understand, why not create one function/method that excepts an id param. The function can react differently depending on which id is passed?

Comment: Well the functions are being passed into a class which is then executing them depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
window["step" + directionNumber]();
```

When you write in the global scope

```
function someName(){
}
```

you're defining a property of the global object (`window`) with name `someName` and value the function.

It's equivalent to

```
window.someName = function(){
}
```

So you can call your function as `window.someName();` or, more useful here, as `window['someName']();`

A better solution would probably be to define an array of functions :

```
var stepFunctions = [];
stepFunctions[0] = function(){};
```

then you can call them using `stepFunctions[directionNumber]();`

Comment: Probably want to quote "step".

Comment: Also be warned, this will probably only work with global functions (which is what you'd find in `window`).  For instance, `(function () { var x = function() { }; window["x"](); })() ` will typically throw a TypeError.

Comment: @SLaks Yes, I actually kept getting this, but didn't realize I hadn't been quoting `'step'`! This works perfectly.. You guys rule.

Comment: *"When you write `function someName(){}` you're defining a property of the global object."* This is *only* if the `function someName(){}` is declared in the global scope.

Comment: @cHao You are spot on, it does only work with global(window) functions... is there anything I could add to make it work within a parent function perhaps also? (Just out of curiosity too)

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS: Can't think of anything for local variables.  Even `eval` probably won't work there.  For functions in some other object, though, you could refer to that object for them the same way you refer to `window` to access global stuff.  Which is to say, if you want stuff to be accessible by name, stick it in an object somewhere.  :)  Then the name becomes a key, which is easy to work with dynamically.

Comment: @user1689607 yes... obviously... ^^

Comment: Not necessarily obvious. I had a long battle with someone last week who refused to believe that `function foo(){}` wasn't equivalent to `foo = function(){}` *(no `var` declaration)*.

Comment: ...and your updated answer still suggests that `function someName(){}` creates a property of `window` irrespective of where the declaration is located. Is this what you think? To be clear, `function someName(){}` is not necessarily equivalent to `window.someName = function(){}`

Comment: *"Is this what you think?"* Please stop being offensive when you have a competive answer. You perfectly know we're just trying to make things clear for OP.

Comment: Either way it works like a charm, gave you +1 as well @user1689607 (how do you remember your username lol) I knew @dystroy was refering to the global scope with `function Whatever === window.Whatever`.

Comment: @dystroy: I have no idea why you would be offended. Your updated answer still doesn't correct this mistake, so it could be that you think that syntax creates a global irrespective if its location in code. It's simply wrong. If this offends you, I can't help that. And if you think answers are "competing", then I think you put far too much value on meaningless reputation points.

Comment: Please read my answer instead of trying to see a mistake.

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS: Except that `function Whatever(){}` isn't necessarily equivalent to `window.Whatever = function(){}`. Variable scope plays a very real role.

Comment: @user1689607 EVERYBODY knows it and nobody says otherwise.

Comment: @dystroy: Yes, I do see now that you had moved the wording around. You don't need to be so easily offended when you are corrected. You know that the wording started off being entirely incorrect, and it took a couple different edits for you to get it worded correctly.

Comment: I find it fine when you precise something to OP or other readers because it might avoid a mistake and when you suggest to make it clearer. If find it offensive when you try to suggest, even after OP says he understood, that a seasoned javascript coder could have missed this basic point.

Comment: Yes, my comment to OP came after your final update, and I didn't see that you had the wording moved around in your last edit. So it seemed to be that OP was referring to the previous incorrect wording. This sort of confusion is what happens when there are multiple revisions to correct a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Store your functions in an Object to dynamically access them by name.

```
var funcs = {};

funcs.step1 = function(){ console.log("foo"); };
funcs.step2 = function(){ console.log("bar"); };
```

---

```
var text = "step",
    number = 1;

funcs[text + number](); // foo

++number;

funcs[text + number](); // bar
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking this as well - dystroy's answer certainly works and answers the question, but packing the functions into a separate object seems more sensible than throwing them into the window.